# Is there a way to create labels with tkinter by pushing a button

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I have a program where I want it to store information written by the user, except I want it to store it in a window and constantly make new labels and buttons for each time the user stores that data. However, I can't find a way for the code itself to add labels to the program. Writing a bunch of labels to be later enabled beforehand seems impractical and I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: You should be able to generate labels on command and show them using a display manager? It would help if you could post a [mcve].

Comment: You can use a `Text` widget to hold the required information instead of bunch of `Label`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from creating a widget from a button. Just create a command that creates a label, and call it from a button.

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_label():
    count = len(root.winfo_children())
    label = tk.Label(root, text=f"Label #{count}")
    label.pack(side="top")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Create label", command=create_label)
button.pack(side="top")
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to be able to access those labels later, add them to a global array or dictionary:

```
labels = []
def create_label():
    count = len(root.winfo_children())
    label = tk.Label(root, text=f"Label #{count}")
    label.pack(side="top")
    labels.append(label)
```

If you want to create a label with one or more buttons, I recommend creating a custom class. Here's an example that emulates a "TO DO" item, with a button that destroys itself. This isn't particularly good design, but it shows the general concept.

```
class TodoItem(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, text):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=text, anchor="w")
        self.delete = tk.Button(self, text="Delete", command=self.delete)
        self.delete.pack(side="right")
        self.label.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    def delete(self):
        self.destroy()
```

You can then treat it like any other widget, including being able to create it from a button click:

```
def create_label():
    count = len(root.winfo_children())
    item = TodoItem(root, f"This is item #{count}")
    item.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can do that pretty easy. The below example could definitely be considered differently, but it illustrates the fundamental principle behind what you want to do.

```
import tkinter as tk

#create root
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

#configure grid
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

#just a container for generated labels
label_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe', columnspan=3)

#instructions for this example
tk.Label(root, text='enter label text and click create', anchor='w').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')

#entry field for example purposes
label_ent = tk.Entry(root)
label_ent.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='we')

#called when the button is clicked
def create_label(master, row, column, sticky='w', **kwargs):
    #really, it's as simple as creating a label and adding it to the display
    #~ with grid, pack or place, within a function that is called by a button
    tk.Label(master, **kwargs).grid(row=row, column=column, sticky=sticky)
    
#button that creates labels
tk.Button(root, text='create', command=lambda: create_label(label_frame, 
                                                            row=len(label_frame.winfo_children()), 
                                                            column=0, 
                                                            text=label_ent.get())).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does `columnconfigure()` and  `rowconfigure()` do?

Comment: @CoolCloud - Google it. The answer is too long for a comment. In the shortest possible terms, based on how I used them, they work together like `pack(fill='both', expand=True)`, but not exactly.